# How to modify a column present in a mysql database through python?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm able to connect with my database. But I want to change the values present in that particular column.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM foo;")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Output of the above code is,

```
('foo,bar,foo,bar',)
('foobar,bar',)
('foo,bar,buz,buz',)
```

I'm able to replace the value by,

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(re.sub(r'^[^,]*,', '', row[0]))
cursor.close()
```

returns,

```
bar,foo,bar
bar
bar,buz,buz
```

but I don't know how to setback the altered string to that particular  column.

I think i need to use `update` query, so I tried

```
for row in rows:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE foo SET  categories=%s;", re.sub(r'^[^,]*,', '', row[0]))
```

But it returns an error message of,

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1
```

Comment: @nu11p01n73R nooo, it would turn the corresponding column to `%s`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Do you have tried my deleted answer? or do you write the all of your columns within the query? maybe you have an `ID`

Comment: @Kasra i tried, 1st fails with the error message i mentioned. 2nd one shows error at the `%` symbol.

Comment: I have a doubt of, why we loop through each row where this `UPDATE drug_specifications SET  categories=%s;` query applies to the whole.

Comment: What about `"UPDATE drug_specifications SET  categories={};".format(re.sub(r'^[^,]*,', '', row[0]))`

Comment: it still shows the error..

Comment: Is the names of your columns correct? and what about using `format`?

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'bar,foo where categories=foo,bar,foo' at line 1`

Comment: I have run a lot of queries like this few month ago and all of them works. maybe you write your column names incorrect or maybe its an impact between your MYSQL and Python?? 0_o

Comment: @Kasra is that the db table really altered after running the query from python? pls get into this room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79669/tmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in comment you need to specify the column ID for your query :

```
for row in rows:
        sub=re.sub(r'^[^,]*,', '', row[0])
        cursor.execute("UPDATE drug_specifications SET  categories=%s where id=%s;",(sub, str(row[0])))
```